# Session not set in beforeFilter() when having authComponent

Tags: php, session, cakephp

I have a problem in my CakePHP application which is that there is no Session object available in my AppController beforeFilter() function, but only when I have Auth Component in it. I have the following code to set the site's language:

```
public function beforeFilter() {
    $this->_setLanguage();
    $locale = Configure::read('Config.language');
    $path = APP . 'View' . DS . $locale . DS . $this->viewPath;
    if ($locale && file_exists($path)) {
        $this->viewPath = $locale . DS . $this->viewPath;
    }
}

protected function _setLanguage() {
    if (!$this->Session->check('Config.language')) {
        $langLetters = isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE']) ? $_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'] : 'en';
        $browserLanguage = substr($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'], 0, 2);
        switch ($browserLanguage){
            case "en":
                $this->Session->write('Config.language', 'en');
                break;
            case "pt":
                $this->Session->write('Config.language', 'pt');
                break;
            default:
                $this->Session->write('Config.language', 'en');
        }
    }
    Configure::write('Config.language', $this->Session->read('Config.language'));
}
```

Problem is that, when I add:

```
public $components = array('Auth');
```

I get the following error:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function check() on a non-object in /home/brasilgameshow/www/teste_credenciamento/app/Controller/AppController.php on line 73
```

which is the first line of the _setLanguage() function. That means that I simply don't have the Session object anymore when Auth component is present. Could anybody suggest a workaround which wouldn't compromise Auth component's security? I mean, would simply initializing a new session when there is none set be a good solution?

Comment: Try adding both components `public $components = array('Auth', 'Session');`

Comment: I had just realized that, thanks a lot! It turns out that I simply had no components defined and then Cake seems to default to Session only, but doesn't consider Session when I define my own components, which is understandable.

Comment: Great ... Add this as an answer and mark it as accepted so that no one bothers to get in here to help you :).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default if you don't add any components CakePHP would load its default components (Session)

When you tried to invoke your own components array (with Auth in this case) you should include all other components you may need

Answer (score 0):

**SOLUTION FOUND**

As Ayman pointed at the comments, when adding your own array of components in AppController, Session needs to be included! Thanks!